# Responsibility for memory deallocation in COM Interop

Tags: c#, c++, com, com-interop, safearray

I'm working on a C++ code consuming services provided by a .NET dll, which I'm accessing via COM Interop. I'm writing both the C++ and C# side.

One of the methods that is exposed by the dll and is called from the C++, asks the dll
to return an allocated byte array containing some information. After creating that method in my C# code, the .tlb generator exposed it as follows:

```
HRESULT _stdcall DownloadData(
                        [out] SAFEARRAY(unsigned char)* outputBuf);
```

Testing has shown that when I send the pointer as required I do get the buffer allocated
and filled with the information I need, but I don't understand in this scenario whose responsibility it is (C#\C++) to deallocate this memory and how.

Any advice? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard [COM memory allocation rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686638%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) still apply to interop. It's the responsibility of the caller (the client code consuming the C# DLL) to release `outputBuf` array (using [SafeArrayDestroy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221702%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Comment: Although the caller is not who allocated the actual memory?

Comment: Correct. The callee (C# interop code, behind the scene) will allocate the memory, and the caller (C++ code) should free it when no longer needed.