# Out parameters deallocation in an out of process COM server

Tags: windows, memory, com

I have an out of process COM server which has the following method:
    STDMETHODIMP CMyCom::process(/*[out]*/BSTR* pResponse);

In this method I allocate memory for the pResponse attribute as follows:
    *pResponse = ::SysAllocString("Some string");

My question is, when the method returns, who takes the responsibility for freeing the memory allocated for this BSTR? Is it the COM subsystem?

Comment: Likely a duplicate of [Responsibility for memory deallocation in COM Interop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18679659/1768303).

Comment: [Allocating and Releasing Memory for a BSTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xda6xzx7%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
   STDMETHODIMP CMyCom::process(/*[out]*/BSTR* pResponse);
```

It must be attributed with [out, retval] to be COM Automation compatible.  The Automation contract demands that the caller deallocates it after using the string.  Any automation client gets this right.

Comment: What if the client is a Java class which is calling the COM server using jInterop? In such a case, how will the memory be freed?